Unable to scroll to absolute bottom if there is a footer with position: sticky
I have setup virtuoso with a position: sticky; Footer (<ExpiredNotice />):
CSS:
    "& div.virtuoso": {

        "& section:last-of-type": {

            position: "sticky",
            bottom: "16px",
            paddingLeft: "16px",
            paddingRight: "16px",
            marginTop: "30px",

        },

    }

CODE:
            <Virtuoso
                ref={ref}
                className={"virtuoso"}
                style={{
                    ....
                }}
                context={{ ... }}
                totalCount={props.messages.length}
                itemContent={
                    (index) => {

                        return (

                            <Message
                                ref={el => (allMessageRefs.current[index] = el)}
                                key={index}
                                index={index}
                                message={props.messages[index]}
                            />

                        )

                    }
                }
                headerFooterTag="section"
                components={{
                    Header: () => (
                        <loadMore />
                    ),
                    Footer: () => (
                        <ExpiredNotice />
                    )

                }}
            />

I want the container <div> (<div data-test-id="virtuoso-scroller" ....>) to scroll to the absolute bottom when button is clicked / triggered.
but it seems impossible when the Footer <div> container itself is position: sticky;

ScollToIndex Code:
  ref.current?.scrollToIndex({
      index: props.messages.length - 1,
      behavior: "instant",
  })

the above scroll the to bottom of the last element of the list, before the Footer <section>
Is there a way to make it possible to be able to scroll to the absolute bottom of the scrollable <div> even when the last child is a sticky Footer?
Looking for a solution or just any workaround that will make it possible
